# Is there any short form call a Singleton variable?

Tags: swift, singleton

I have this singleton class and I need know how can I call the `projects` variable from different view controllers without having to write a long name, example: `ProjectsManager.sharedInstance.projects`.

I don't know if exist another way to do this.

```
class ProjectsManager: NSObject {

     static let sharedInstance = ProjectsManager()

     var projects = [Project]()

     //..

}
```

Comment: No, there is no shortcut syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the Swift 3 naming convention, you can replace `sharedInstance` with `shared`. This is seen in `UserDefaults.standard`, `NotificationCenter.default`, `UIApplication.shared`, etc.

Also, within a view controller you can simply declare a property set to that singleton.

For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var projectsManager = ProjectsManager.shared

    func doSomething() {
        let projects = projectsManager.projects
    }

    // ...

}
```

Both of these should reduce the length of what you need to type each time you use the singleton.